# Errors running pulseeffects (doesn't launch)

Tags: pulse-audio

I installed pulseeffects and for the first run it throw some warnings mostly about missing plugins:

```
$ pulseeffects

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.611: compressor plugin was not found!

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.618: equalizer plugin was not found!

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.664: loudness plugin was not found!

(pulseeffects:2004): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:44:54.681: g_settings_bind: no property 'faster' on class 'ladspa-ladspa-rubberband-so-rubberband-pitchshifter-stereo'

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.707: delay plugin was not found!

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.707: rnnoise plugin was not found!

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.722: compressor plugin was not found!

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.723: equalizer plugin was not found!

(pulseeffects:2004): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:44:54.729: g_settings_bind: no property 'faster' on class 'ladspa-ladspa-rubberband-so-rubberband-pitchshifter-stereo'

(pulseeffects:2004): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 14:44:54.804: rnnoise plugin was not found!
```

however it launched despite missing plugins (eg. equalizer which I wanted the most) But after closing it, I can't run it again:

```
$ pulseeffects
(pulseeffects:2021): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 14:57:16.399: Unable to look up enum nick ‘Downward’ via GType

(pulseeffects:2021): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 14:57:16.399: The schema default value for key 'mode' in schema 'com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects.compressor' was rejected by the binding mapping function.
zsh: trace trap  pulseeffects
```

invoking `pulseeffects -r` and system reboot also had no effect and still displays same errors.

tried `apt remove --purge pulseeffects` and re-installed but problem is still there.

my questions:
How can I get it to work?
How can I add or install it with all plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

**The schema default value for key 'mode' in schema 'com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects.compressor' was rejected by the binding mapping function.**

I tried to remove the config of the plugin "compressor" in the file `.config/PulseEffects/input/Profile Input.json`, but it didn't work.

I think that the problem was that I installed a system update (Arch Linux in my case) but I forgot installing the update for the pulseeffects-legacy AUR Package.

When I updated pulseeffects-legacy, it worked again. I updated from version 4.8.5-4 to 4.8.6-1.

Comment: Tysm for the answer, however the newest available version in my repo is 4.8.4-1 (same that I installed, purged, reinstalled). the related github page says it's in maintenance mode. now my biggest question is why it run only once after first installation and never again.